# RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded

Tags: flutter

I get the following error when the widget length is greater than that of the screen. I am sure I am missing something basic here.

Here is the code:

```
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CarouselImages(widget.store.pictures),
                    StoreDetails(
                      store: widget.store,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

The complete error message:

```
═══════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
The affected RenderFlex is: RenderFlex#c1cb1 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

What am I missing out here?

Comment: I think you need to wrap the single child scroll view in an expanded widget

Comment: If you are expanding your scroll to the whole screen then remove the outer level column, you don't need it.

Comment: @Kris the error remains the same.

Comment: @Kashifa I have few other widgets which gets displayed over the ```SingleChildScrollView```.